# How do I get rid of the white space under and above image

Tags: css, image, border, padding

I have an image which has a border around it and the code looks like this:

```
img{
 display: block;
 border: 2px solid #000;
 height: 140px;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 0;
}

<img src="pathtoimage.png" alt="product name" />
```

I get a small 1px high white gap between the upper and lower borders and the image. I have tried putting the image in a container and setting the border to the container, but the gap still appears. I have tried setting position to absolute and relative, but they didn't work. I have tried using css3's box-size, but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work as is. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PVe7Y/5/).

I think the problem is your actual picture. Are you 100% sure it doesn't have some small white border in the image itself? Try to replace `pathtoimage.png` with `http://placehold.it/350x150` and see if the white edges are gone.

Lastly, try setting `padding: 0 !important;` to make sure it isn't inheriting padding from somewhere else.

Comment: Anders, tak. Jeg er en fjols. Jeg har lig tjekket billedet og det er faktisk der, hvor problemet ligger. The image is a PNG with transparant canvas and the canvase is 2px higher than the actual image. I should have checked that first. Tak for hjaelpen

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of edges around elements: padding, margin and border.

Add:

```
margin: 0;
```

Here is an image explaining which is which:

[image: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/cascading-style-sheets/how-are-margins-borders-padding-and-content-related/how-are-margins-borders-padding-and-content-related-01.gif]

Comment: Margin should create space outside the border, not between the border and the picture.

Comment: Is it not inheriting padding from somewhere too? And aren't the white lines accidentally part of the image itself?